# Which $K$-groups $K(C^*_r(G))$ are computed?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, cohomology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

We have the Pimsner-Voiculescu exact sequences and the Baum-Connes map
for possible computation of the $K$-theory of the reduced group $C^*$-algebra $C^*_r(G)$ for a topological, locally compact, second-countable Hausdorff group $G$.

Up to now I have not seen much computations of $K(C^*_r(G))$.

Has anyone references to such computations, in particular in computing the left hand side of the Baum-Connes map, under the Chern map.
That is, computations of the Czech cohomology groups
$$\lim_{X \subseteq \underline EG} H(X,G)$$
(something like that).

Comment: Minor question: do you mean Čech (as opposed to Czech) cohomology?

Comment: As a matter of fact, Čech in Czech means Czech and Čech was Czech. :-)

Comment: I worked one year in Prague, so perhaps I got some feeling for Czech.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some known computations for infinite discrete groups. Basically, most of these proceed by computing the equivariant K-homology of the classifying space of proper actions and deduce the computation for K-theory of the group $C^\ast$-algebra via the assembly map.

For the Bianchi groups:

- A.D. Rahm. On the equivariant K-homology of ${\rm PSL}_2$ of the imaginary quadratic integers. Ann. Inst. Fourier 66 (2016), 1667-1689. [(link to journal page)](http://aif.cedram.org/aif-bin/fitem?id=AIF_2016__66_4_1667_0)

Computations for Heisenberg-type groups have been established in the thesis of Olivier Isely [(link)](https://doc.rero.ch/record/28552/files/Isely_Olivier_-_K-theory_and_K-homology_for_semi-direct_products_of_Z2_by_Z_UNINE_THESE_2246_2011.pdf)

Right-angled Coxeter groups:

- R. Sanchez-Garcia: Equivariant K-homology for some Coxeter groups. J. London Math. Soc. 75 (2007), 773-790. [(link to arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604402)

For hyperbolic reflection groups:

- J-F. Lafont, I.J. Ortiz, A.D. Rahm, R.J. Sanchez-Garcia: Equivariant K-homology for hyperbolic reflection groups. arXiv:1707.05133 [(link to arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05133)

The last paper also contains discussion and many further literature references to further computations of K-theory of group $C^\ast$-algebras, most notably by Wolfgang Lück and collaborators. There is also a book in progress on the isomorphism conjectures which contains a chapter on computations, see [Wolfgang Lück's homepage](http://www.him.uni-bonn.de/lueck/).

Answer (score 5):

There are some recent papers of Valette and coauthors which give explicit calculations/descriptions of the K-theory for some of the Baumslag-Solitar groups, namely BS($1,n$) (Pooya and Valette, arXiv [1604.05607](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05607)), and also for certain lamplighters over ${\bf Z}$ (Flores, Pooya and Valette, arXiv [1610.02798](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02798)). In both cases, the authors determine the LHS and the RHS of the Baum-Connes "picture" separately, and then verify explicitly that the BC map is an isomorphism.

(Apologies if these examples are covered in the references already provided by Matthias Wendt.)